# The below query is executing perfectly on sqlyog but its not working with CI $this->db->query($sql)

Tags: php, mysql, join

Query:

```
SELECT em.`Full_Name`,em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`,COUNT(dm.`Account_ID`) AS 
No_of_Doctors ,COUNT(p.`Doctor_Id`)AS No_of_Doctors_profiled,rt.`target` AS   
Target_New_Rxn_for_the_month,SUM(rp.`Planned_Rx`) AS 
Planned_New_Rxn,COUNT(ap.`Act_Plan`) AS No_of_Doctors_planned,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ar.`Activity_Done`='Yes' THEN 1 END) AS checkk
FROM ( SELECT `VEEVA_Employee_ID`,`Full_Name` FROM Employee_Master
WHERE `Reporting_VEEVA_ID` = 'gi00145822') AS em 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.`Account_ID`, ed.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` FROM Doctor_Master d 
INNER JOIN Employee_Doc ed ON ed.`VEEVA_Account_ID` = d.`Account_ID` AND `ed`.`Status`='1'
WHERE `VEEVA_Employee_ID` IN (SELECT `VEEVA_Employee_ID` FROM Employee_Master WHERE `Reporting_VEEVA_ID` = 'gi00145822') 
AND d.`Individual_Type` = 'Doctor' ) AS dm ON em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` = dm.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Doctor_Id`, `VEEVA_Employee_ID` FROM Profiling WHERE `Product_Id` = 6 AND `STATUS` = 'Submitted' AND `Cycle` = 2 GROUP BY `Doctor_Id`, `VEEVA_Employee_ID`) AS
p ON em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` = p.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` AND dm.`Account_ID` = p.`Doctor_Id` 
LEFT JOIN Rx_Target rt ON em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`=rt.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`AND rt.`Status`='Submitted' AND rt.`Product_Id`=6 AND rt.`Month`=12 AND rt.`Year`=2016
LEFT JOIN Rx_Planning rp ON dm.`Account_ID` = rp.`Doctor_Id` AND rp.`Approve_Status` ='Approved' AND rp.`Product_Id`=6 AND rp.`Month`=12 AND rp.`Year`=2016 AND rp.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` = em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`
LEFT JOIN Activity_Planning ap ON dm.`Account_ID` = ap.`Doctor_Id` AND ap.`Approve_Status` = 'Approved' AND ap.`Product_Id`=6 AND ap.`Month`=12 AND ap.`Year`=2016 AND em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` = ap.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`
LEFT JOIN Activity_Reporting ar ON dm.`Account_ID` = ar.`Doctor_Id` AND ar.`Approve_Status` = 'Approved' AND ar.`Product_Id`=6 AND ar.`Month`=12 AND ar.`Year`=2016 AND em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` = ar.`VEEVA_Employee_ID` 
GROUP BY em.`VEEVA_Employee_ID`
```

It executing perfectly on **sqlyog** but its not working with CI $this->db->query($sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got the solution.

its exits the current process in middle.

i allocate resources.

ini_set('max_execution_time',300);

and

ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

and works perfectly.

anyway thank you all.